# Is it possible to define an anonymous selector in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector, anonymous-methods

I'd like to be able to define an inline anonymous selector that a selector wherever a selector is needed as an argument.

Is this possible, or do I have to just suck it up and define a method?

***Background***: In my iPhone application I need to update my UI from another thread. To do this I use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` However, I'd like to be able to get this functionality without having to define a whole other method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The idea is self-contradictory — a selector *is* a name. That's all it is. It doesn't define any functionality.

Objective-C didn't have any kind of anonymous function until just recently when blocks were introduced into Mac OS X. It's possible to use them on the iPhone through [Plausible Blocks](http://code.google.com/p/plblocks/), but they're still not integrated into the APIs there.

### Update 2014

This answer was correct back in 2009, but by now Apple has integrated [blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) very well into the iOS frameworks. They're used pretty pervasively for callbacks now and are heavily used in the Grand Central Dispatch concurrency library.